# Why or how to use NUnit methods with ICollection<T>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Some of `NUnit`'s Assert methods are overloaded to use `ICollection` but not `ICollection<T>` and thus you can't use them.

Is there anyway around this? Heck, am I doing something stupid?

I'm having to drop back to using `Assert.AreEqual` rather than specialised methods and its making my tests ugly.

Any advice?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the responses. The `That` method of NUnit seems interesting so I'll look into it at a later date.

Mark correctly mentioned this, but [NUnit Collection Asserts](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.4.1) are excellent. I've recently used them on some new tests and found them excellent to work with.

Comment: I should mention, in my class I'm testing. Chaning the method return type to List<T> instead of IList solves this problem but in turn I am exposing List<T> which I don't want to for reasons heavily discussed on SO etc.. already.

Comment: There should be no harm in using linq to turn your collection into a list, as long as you aren't asserting anything that is not present in the collection. Asserting that the ForEach method works for instance would be bad form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ICollection` and `ICollection<T>` are different contracts - one does not inherit the other.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection_members.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2fx0ty0.aspx

If you have a generic collection you can call `ToList()` on it and get a `List<T>`, which happens to implement the non-generic `ICollection` as well.  Then use that List in the NUnit Assert method.

Comment: Smashing. Linq saved the day (yet again). Cheers, didn't think of this.

Comment: Linq might not be saving the day, just giving you a rose tinted recollection that will lead to disappointment later.

Comment: Well it gave me ToList(), I'm happy.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but for generic collections instead of using:

```
Assert.Contains(member, list);
```

I use:

```
Assert.That(list.Contains(member));
```

which I find almost as readable.

Comment: Thanks! That allows avoiding a useless `ToList()`.

And I would argue that it's even more readable: you can litteraly read it as a sentence ;)

Answer (score 7):

There are a set of CollectionAsserts, or you could inherit your test from AssertHelper and use syntax like

```
Expect(actual, Is.EquivalentTo(expected));
```

A look at the documentation should give you the syntax for the constraints that apply to collections.

Here's a [link](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.5.2) (this is version 2.5.2)

N.B. Expect is just shorthand for Assert.That...

Comment: Your answer is better than the accepted one, what a pity. Only 3 minutes late to acceptdom.